# Como optimizar dos funciones que son muy parecidas

Tags: python

Tengo estas dos funciones que son muy parecidas y me pregunto si hay alguna forma de optimizar esto para no repetir tanto código

```
def show_data(file, id, info):
    results = read_data(file)
    id = str(id)
    for data in results:
        if data[f"{info}_id"] == id:
            return data
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
        )

def delete_data(file, id, info):
    results = read_data(file)
    id = str(id)
    for data in results:
        if data[f"{info}_id"] == id:
            results.remove(data)
            overwrite_data(file, results)
            return data
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
        )
```

La única diferencia que tienen es en la segunda función estas dos líneas:

```
results.remove(data)
overwrite_data(file, results)
```

Comment: Un tercer parámetro que le diga a tu función si debe o no correr esas líneas de código

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando un flag adicional:

```py
def fun_data(file, id, info, flag):
    results = read_data(file)
    id = str(id)
    for data in results:
        if data[f"{info}_id"] == id:
           if flag == 1:
               results.remove(data)
               overwrite_data(file, results)
           return data
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
        )
```

Comment: un valor por defecto al flag no vendría mal

Answer (score 0):

Yo preferiría una manera más explicita que usar flags. Divide tus tareas en partes más pequeñas y específicas que puedas reutilizar.

```
def show_data(results, file, id, info):
    id = str(id)
    for data in results:
        if data[f"{info}_id"] == id:
            return data
        else:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!",
            )


def delete_data(results, data):
    results.remove(data)
    return data


results = read_data(file)

try:
    data = show_data(results, tuArchivo, tuID, tuInfo)
except HTTPException:
    data = None

if data:
    delete_data(results, data)
    overwrite_data(file, results)
else:
    print(f"[ERROR] Datos vacios")
```

No veo el resto del código así que no sé hasta qué punto esto sería válido o si directamente pudiera hacerse de otra forma totalmente distinta cambiando más código base.

En resumen la idea es deslocalizar los datos de las operaciones; sacas leer `results` de tus funciones y los pasas como argumento para buscar `data`. Después "sólo si" `data` tiene información puedes borrarla de `results` y ya sabes que existe porque solo tendrá información válida o valdrá `None` si no y saltará el error de datos vacíos.

No soy muy fan de la excepción HTTPException cuando la función no tiene nada que ver con eso, pero ya he hecho muchos cambios...

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, puedes llamar `show_data` desde `delete_data` y hacer las líneas de código ahí.

```py
def show_data(file, id, info):
    results = read_data(file)
    id = str(id)
    for data in results:
        if data[f"{info}_id"] == id:
            return data
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
        )

def delete_data(file, id, info):
    results = read_data(file)
    results.remove(show_data(file, id, info))
    overwrite_data(file, results)
    return data
```

Tendrías que añadir la parte de gestionar la excepción.

Comment: Yo tambien pensé lo mismo pero `results` es una variable local a `show_data()`. En mi respuesta lo he intentado solucionar sacando results de la función

Comment: @JoseRodriguez bueno, en mi respuesta `results = read_data(file)` está en ambas funciones.

Comment: Cierto, todavia no llevo mi tercer café del día y los ojos me castigan ;)

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar un bucle, emplea una *compresión de listas* para averiguar si hay algun elemento que cumpla la condición:

En vez de:

```py
    for data in results:
        if data[f"{info}_id"] == id:
            return data
        else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
        )
```

Escribirlo así:

```py
found = (data for data in results if data[f"{info}_id"] == id)
data = next(found, None)  # localizar primer elemento

if data is None:
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
    )
else:
    return data
```

Lo juntamos y hacemos una única función:

```py
def process_data(action="show", file, id, info):

    results = read_data(file)
    id = str(id)

    found = (data for data in results if data[f"{info}_id"] == id)
    data = next(found, None)  # localizar primer elemento
    
    if data is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"¡This {info} doesn't exist!"
        )
    else:
        # diferentes acciones a realizar
        if action == "show":
            return data
        elif action == "delete":
            results.remove(data)
            overwrite_data(file, results)
            return data
```

Si se quiere tener las mismas funciones que antes, se pueden crear funciones parciales:

```py
from functools import partial

show_data = partial(process_data, action="show")
delete_data = partial(process_data, action="delete")
```